# Build Failed when trying to test app on Android phone with API 30 - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I trying to debug app on the Android 11 (API 30).

I enable USB debugging from the options and when I connect phone to computer with cable I see the phone from the debug menu.

When I choose the phone and start the Application I receive error:

```
    InstallPackage
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00169] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:346 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass100_0.<InstallPackage>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:803 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <e068e2227ab74c1bb3d724ebaab0e3ff>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001cf] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:206 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0042f] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:223 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x001c0] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:338 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x0032d] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:355 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.RunTaskAsync () [0x002fb] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:212 
Done building target "_Upload" in project "HydroMeteoAnalyzer.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "HydroMeteoAnalyzer.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00169] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:346 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass100_0.<InstallPackage>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:803 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <e068e2227ab74c1bb3d724ebaab0e3ff>:0 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001cf] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:206 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0042f] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:223 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x001c0] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:338 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x0032d] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:355 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.RunTaskAsync () [0x002fb] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:212 
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:16.77
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00169] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:346 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass100_0.<InstallPackage>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:803 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <e068e2227ab74c1bb3d724ebaab0e3ff>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001cf] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:206 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0042f] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:223 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x001c0] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:338 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x0032d] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:355 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.RunTaskAsync () [0x002fb] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:212 
Done building target "_Upload" in project "HydroMeteoAnalyzer.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "HydroMeteoAnalyzer.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00169] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:346 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass100_0.<InstallPackage>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:803 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <e068e2227ab74c1bb3d724ebaab0e3ff>:0 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001cf] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:206 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackageAsync (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, PushAndInstallCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0042f] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:223 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x001c0] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:338 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.InstallPackage (System.Boolean installed) [0x0032d] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:355 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.RunTaskAsync () [0x002fb] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:212 
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:16.77
```

Is there a way to fix this bug and debug on the phone, because is more fast than emulator ..

Comment: Did you add the runtime Core version to the phone?  See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet

Comment: @jdweng this is not a thing

Comment: Try disabling fast deploy.

Comment: Have you check the target android version? Have you installed the SDKs?